# Custom UITabBar shows a white line below UITabBarItem in iOS10 only

Tags: background-image, line, uitabbar, ios10, uitabbaritem

Since iOS10 has been release we have an issue with one of our project. The customised UITabBar shows a white line below the UITabBarItems, I have tried numerous ways to remove this line, including solutions from stack overflow:

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "menu-background")
UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
```

as well as

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Here is a screenshot of the UITabBar, playing tricks on us
[image]

Comment: Add some more code how you add your tab bar

Comment: I fixed the issue by setting `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 20/255, blue: 42/255, alpha: 1)` instead of setting a background image